# Second HDD automatically stops after 30 seconds of inactivity

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop, power-management

I have ASUS G53JW notebook with two HDDs (2x500GB Seagate ST95005620AS). Second HDD automatically stops after 30 seconds of inactivity. Always. I'm using Windows 7 x64. If I run a game from this HDD there are always lags when something is needed to load after 30 seconds of inactivity of the HDD. Standard power management settings do nothing with this HDD, though "auto shutdown after" property is set to "never".

How to fix it, anyway?

Comment: Maybe look here: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/265376-32-momentus-problems Might be a HDD firmware issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Second HDD automatically stops after 30 seconds of inactivity](http://superuser.com/questions/380781/second-hdd-automatically-stops-after-30-seconds-of-inactivity)

Comment: Are you sure that you set "Turn off hard disk after" under advanced power options to never on every! power mode?

Comment: Is it a Seagate drive? I was reading recently about a firmware update that is supposed to stop the drive from spinning down, which ends up doing the exact opposite.

Comment: @bamboon, not every, only active. But how it is connected? On other power plans there is 10-20 minutes, but NOT 30 seconds.

Comment: @RandolphWest, yes, both HDDs are 500GB Seagate ST95005620AS.

Comment: As I noted previously, I think this is a firmware issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by upgrading HDDs firmware (from official Seagate site) from SD24 to SD28. And now it is OKAY.